# Значение выражения "Жил себе да жил"

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

Подскажите,пожалуйста, что означает выражение:  *"Жил себе да жил"*?
В контексте:"Так вот и наш зверек: он никогда не задумывался над тем, как его зовут, А ПРОСТО ЖИЛ СЕБЕ ДА ЖИЛ в далеком тропическом лесу."

Answer (score 4):

Ориентируясь на Ваш итальянский никнейм... ))) Значение - просто жил. Жил-поживал, никого не трогал. Ничем не прославился и не ославился. Просто обыватель:

> Но обитель свою
>   Разлюбил обитатель...

"[Себе](http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5&from=xx&to=ru&did=ogegova&stype=)" в этом предложение - ч**у**дная старомосковская разговорная частица.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Жил *себе* — жил в рамках своих собственных, явных или неявных, интересов, без значимых контактов с другими людьми, каковые (конфликты и добрые дела) выделяли бы его из общей массы в широкую историческую или просто пространственную известность. Жил себе *да жил* — и проходила такая его жизнь долго во времени. По контексту, однако и к тому же, могут быть попутные вариации.

Answer (score 3):

Неожиданно понял, что вопрос хороший.

С одной стороны, можно признать, что трактовка Galina Avanesova имеет право на существование, в примерах из словарной статьи ничего такая частица(?) не несет, этакая паразитная частица.

У Hetmit'а при внешнем всем сходстве толкования смысл получается другой: независимо, автономно. И тоже правда. Сижу [себе], примус починяю. (У Булгакова в оригинале: "никого не трогаю"). Мне это ближе, но тоже не до конца.

Есть же еще толкование этого "себе" как частицы эмфатической (тоже, естественно, разговорной): "Вполне себе законченный мерзавец" - "себе" здесь усиливает "вполне".

В моем понимании последнее использование более актуальное фиксируемых в словаре. И при первом прочтении, до того, как с другими ответами познакомился, я именно так это "себе" в примере и понял. "Жил *себе*" = "хорошо жил, ни в чем не нуждаясь" (частично совпадает с Hermit, но только частично).

Да, ещё.  Не знаю как там насчет старомосковского, с ним я достаточно знаком, но впервые услышал это "себе" то ли от родственников-одесситов в далеких шестидесятых (раньше - не мог по малолетсву), то ли чуть позже в самой Одессе. И с тех пор не нашел повода менять "прописку" для этого словечка.

Короче, думаю, и тут без контекста не обойтись.
(+)
С учетом контекста (в комментариях), думаю "себе" здесь эквивалентно "ни о чем не заботясь", "в свое удовольствие". Хотя тоже - "возможны варианты".

Comment: Понял,что без контекста не обойтись.  Может быть это выражение будет иметь другой смысл.
Контекст: "Так вот и наш зверек: он никогда не задумывался над тем, как его зовут, А ПРОСТО ЖИЛ СЕБЕ ДА ЖИЛ в далеком тропическом лесу."

Comment: Ну тогда на выбор - или мое толкование или Hermit'а. Думаю, оба возможны. Или "независимо", "автономно", "сам по себе" или просто для усиления первого "жил". Здесь это "жил"  явно противопоставляется каким-то "философским" идеям поиска самоназвания и смысла жизни, упоминаемым в первой части фразы. "Себе" - конкретного смысла здесь не несет, но дает акцент на простоту жизни.

Comment: ...никогда не задумывался над тем, как его зовут, А ПРОСТО ЖИЛ СЕБЕ ДА ЖИЛ. ===========  Если далеко не уходить от такого стиля и выбора слов, тогда так: Жил — не тужил.